# Quick steps with layers in PS

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, shortcuts

I'm new here. I was wondering if is there a way to separate the six elements from this layer 1 into six different layers like the image below in a **single step.**

For now I'm using the lasso tools and then ctrl+shift+J to cut the selection in a new layer, this steps for every element.

TKS a lot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure that the way you are doing it is already the quickest way.

Comment: The way you're doing it is probably the quickest. However, for certain processes that you need to repeat over and over, you could create an 'action'. see below

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZC2qHx_Tdh8

Answer (score -1):

I think the manual method is the best, but check out this script:
https://photoshopscripts.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/split-to-layers/

Comment: Hi Lenny, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

Comment: Hi Vincent, you are right link-only answers are not the best. But, in the link is a Ps script that apparently solves Arturo´s problem. In this case its a download-and-check action, as simple as that.